# Simple way to play a sound file (.aif)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, audio

I'm making an app for Mac OS X using Xcode, and I want it to play a alert sound when something happens.

What is the simplest code for playing a sound in Objective-C/Cocoa? Note that my sound file is an `.aif`.

Also, where do I put the sound file inside my project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To play audio on the Mac, you can either use [`NSSound`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for basic activities, or the more robust [`CoreAudio`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) framework for more complicated tasks.

---

If you were to use `NSSound` to achieve this goal, your code would look something like this:

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"replace-with-file-name" ofType:@"aif"];
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:resourcePath byReference:YES];
// Do something with sound, like [sound play] and release.
```

OR

```
NSSound *sound = [NSSound soundNamed:@"replace-with-file-name-without-the-extension"];
// Do something with sound, like [sound play], but don't release (it's autoreleased).
```

If you were to use the second snippet, you would have to ensure that the sound file's extension is `aiff` and not just `aif`, since `+soundNamed:` looks for very specific file extensions; I don't think `aif` is on that list.

Using `CoreAudio` is more complicated, so if you just want to play it and mess around with very simple settings, just use `NSSound`

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example of how to use NSSound in the code ?

Comment: Thanks it worked, just one more question: I sound was for example 1min and I release it, does it keep playing ?

Comment: Andy, the [NSSound Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states that a sound will stop playing once it has been deallocated: "Upon deallocation, a sound object stops playback of the sound (as needed) so that it can free up the corresponding audio resources." So if you create a sound, start playing it, then release it before it has finished playing, the sound will stop.

Answer (score 10):

Basic playback of sound is quite easy.

You can use the [`NSSound`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000393) class to load the file in a few different ways, for example, by name:

```
NSSound * myAwesomeSound = [NSSound soundNamed:@"AwesomeSound"];
```

<sub>This will need to be retained if you want to keep it around.</sub>

in this case the class will search certain particular directories, including your application bundle, for a sound file with that name. One important note is that the file must have the `.aiff` (with *two* f's) extension in order to be found by this method.*

You would probably store the sound file in the Resources folder of your project; that's where "media" files are commonly kept.

Then you can play it very simply, perhaps using a button press:

```
- (IBAction)playTheSound:(id)sender {
    NSSound * myAwesomeSound = [NSSound soundNamed:@"AwesomeSound"];
    [myAwesomeSound play];
}
```

It's also possible to do some basic transport control: pausing, stopping, checking whether the sound has finished, and so on.  Please see the [Sound Programming Topics Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sound/) for details.

---

*It's possible to use other formats, too, of course.

Answer (score 1):

For example, add the AudioToolbox framework, the add the sound file to your resources / project, then add the below to your .h:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

And then: (after @interface { blah } in your .h)

```
- (IBAction) playSound;
```

Add the following to your .m: (change 'Ping' and 'wav' to the respective file name and type)

```
- (IBAction) playSound
{
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Ping" ofType:@"wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); 
    [soundFile release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and add your .aif files to your project in Xcode as follows:

1. Command-click on the Classes folder (from within xCode)
2. Select Add > Existing Files
3. Navigate to the directory containing your .aif and select it(them). Click Add.
   (optional: Check the “Copy items” checkbox & Click Add.)

See Apple's examples & great info: [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SysSound/Introduction/Intro.html) & [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007426).