# Playing .wav C Mac

Tags: c

I am looking for a simple way to play a .wav file in my c program. I have googled ways to do this but most answers come up with PlaySound() for windows, and I am running mac. Any answer is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is your program using Cocoa, or is it a console application? What are your needs?

Comment: If you're using Cocoa, there's already an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022729/simple-way-to-play-a-sound-file-aif

Comment: @cabellicar123 then take reference from my answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `afplay` terminal command on Mac to play a sound file like `wav` or `mp3`. Since you can run commands in C with `system()`, you can simply use the following code:

```
int main() {
    system("afplay sound.wav");
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```