# Xcode system("afplay music.wav"); doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, xcode, terminal

I am writing a Command-Line C Application when after browsing through stack overflow I found this: [Playing .wav C Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486347/playing-wav-c-mac), the answers state that using system("afplay music.wav"); plays music, but this doesn't seem to be working for me, I stored the music exactly where my main.c is located. I am not using any external libraries and I am not a pro at c so it would be appreciated if you would simplify things :)

Here is the code

```
void main()
{
    system("afplay IntroSpeechByGuide.wav");
}
```

Comment: how does it not work? does system call fail, does it take the length of music.wav to return, or does it return right away? what is the return value of `system`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There seem to be no errors it's just that the audio doesn't play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I stored the music exactly where my main.c

Most likely, *afplay* cannot find the audio file. The current directory of your application is certainly not the directory where your *main.c* is.

Either provide the full path to the audio file:

```
void main()
{
    system("afplay /Users/me/Documents/AudioFiles/IntroSpeechByGuide.wav");
}
```

Or change the working directory to the directory where the audio file is. It can be changed by going to *Product* / *Scheme* / *Edit Scheme*.

Comment: There that has worked thanks a lot